# Delete Button in PHP generated table, deleting from database and page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to get the delete button on this generated table to work (deleting the database record and deleting the row from the view). The button is being generated through the echo statement in the for loop.

PHP code spitting out the view:

```
<?php
      //Waitlist for Nobel Floorplans
                $sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM wlist");
                $sth->execute();

                $results = $sth->fetchAll();

                $wishlistArray[] = null;
                foreach ($results as $result) {
                     echo "<tr><td>".$result['first_name']."</td><td>".$result['last_name']."</td><td><button class=\"delete_class\" id=\"".$result['id']."\" >DELETE</button></td></tr>";
                }

?>
```

The bottom of this PHP page, is this javascript f(x):

```
<script>
    $(".delete_class").click(function(){
        var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'delete_page.php',
            data: {delete_id : del_id},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) { 
                    tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM wlist WHERE id = ?', [delete_id], success, error);
                }
                else { // DO SOMETHING
                }
            }
            });
    });
</script>
```

The problem with the above code, is that the URL 'delete_page.php" isn't being referred to, and nothing's being deleted from the database.. that, and the "success: function(data) isn't being called at all..

I have the "delete_page.php" in the same folder as the PHP file containing all the above code. This file has this code:

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['delete_id'];
    $query = "delete from nobel_waitlist where ID = $id";
?>
```

It would also be great to know how to AJAX delete that row in that view as well as deleting the database record..

Comment: Please consider what would happen if I sent a `POST` request to your `delete_page.php` with the `id` parameter set to the value `0 OR 1=1`

Comment: I'm a tad worried about the answer to this, but what is `tx` in your success case?

Comment: `last_name,` < that trailing comma in your query should be throwing you an MySQL syntax error and is killing your query. But you're NOT looking for those errors, are you?

Comment: Lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: `DELETE FROM wlist WHERE id = ?` and that needs preparing, so we don't know if you are or not. No idea what that `executeSql()` function looks like.

Comment: *Yoohoo!!* up here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @Fred-ii- I ll delete my answer.. :)

Comment: @MarkB please help me make this more efficient..

Comment: @VickyGonsalves there's an unknown about their `executeSql()` function and I didn't want to post an answer because of it. However, their trailing comma in their SELECT, is killing it. Edit: and OP took it out. Glad I didn't post an answer about it.

Comment: I didn't have that comma in the actual code, I deleted extra variables being brought up on that SELECT statement, forgot about that when posting this question

Comment: @Fred-ii- , I'm not preparing, it, please let me know how

Comment: This `tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM wlist WHERE id = ?'` is ambiguous but is prepared statement syntax.. And I don't know what that function does or how it's executed. To use prepared statements in mysqli, have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and if you're using PDO then http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: In order for that executeSql to work, should I take the tx out? and yes this is using PDO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Alternative Way. I don't know about `executeSql` function, that's why i've given a simple `alert` box.

```
<script>
$('.delete_class').click(function(){
    var del_id= $('.delete_class').val();
    $.ajax({url:"delete_page.php?delete_id="+del_id,cache:false,success:function(result){
        alert("Data Deleted");
    }});
});
</script>
```

**delete_page.php**

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['delete_id'];
$query = "DELETE FROM nobel_waitlist WHERE ID=:id";
$queryResult = $db->prepare($query);
$queryResult->execute(array(':id' => $id));
?>
```

Comment: how do I then go about deleting the row in the table it's in?